# hello how can i show to my page data from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, session

hello how can i show to my page data from 2 different tables. please help me

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../db_connect/db.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: ./login");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM escrow_users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$res2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM escrow_orders WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow2=mysql_fetch_array($res2);


//die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
By doing while statement for query.

```
$query = mysql_query('query_statement');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo '<div>' . $row['field'] . '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your users can have multiple orders. In this case you can use a single query to get all the info you need:

```
SELECT escrow_orders.*, escrow_users.* 
FROM escrow_orders 
JOIN escrow_users ON escrow_users.user_id = escrow_orders.user_id
WHERE escrow_orders.user_id = :userId
```

As a side note, you should stop using `mysql_` functions as they being deprecated. You can use `PDO`, `mysqli_` functions or `MySQLi` object instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
like that  ?

<?php
session_start();
include_once '../db_connect/db.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: ./login");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM escrow_users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']) ;
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$query = mysql_query('escrow_orders');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo '<div>' . $row['name'] . '</div>';
}


//die(mysql_error());

?>
```